# Как используя express-async-router и request вернуть клиенту ответ от другого сервера

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, promise

есть модуль в котором подключены [express-async-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-router) и [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
import { AsyncRouter } from 'express-async-router';
import request from 'request';

const router = new AsyncRouter();
```

далее в одном из роутов понадобилось получать данные из сторонего `API`

```
router.all('/fetchDataFromAPI', () => {    
  request.get('http://someApiUrl', (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(body);      
  });
  return ???;
})
```

Данные получить я смог и консоль это прекрасно отображает, но как мне вернуть их клиенту?

Помогите, я не специалист по `промисам` и `async-await`
версия nodejs 7+ (и вроде как `async-await` есть из коробки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение через промисы:

```
router.all('/fetchDataFromAPI', () => {    
  let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
    request.get('someApiUrl', (error, response, body) => {
      return resolve(body);
    });
  });
  return prom;
})
```